# How to search a specific pattern with commas and digits using egrep

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I have million plus text file containing lines similar to below

```
abc,xyz, =12093|
abc,xyz, =12093, =10998|
```

The first line is fine, but I want to find all the second line. i.e. I want to print all the lines which as pattern   `, =<some number> , =<some number>`

So tried following with egrep without any luck

```
egrep -nr ",\s=\d+,\s=\d+" fileFolder
```

It didn't return any results, but I checked it manually and there were many above mentioned second lines.

interestingly the regex works fine on rubular
http://rubular.com/r/GYynEEoFm7

Does anyone what regex should I use with egrep?

Comment: Does egrep have a switch to enable partial line match? Where maybe the default is full line match. Or it could be backslashes have to be escaped when in double quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\d` isn't supported in grep's regex engine (ERE). Use `[0-9]`

```
egrep -nr ", =[0-9]+, =[0-9]+" fileFolder
```

Comment: Doesen't egrep have extended mode switch? Or am I off base?

Comment: egrep is same as grep -E and \d will only be supported in grep -P

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with `awk`

```
awk '/[0-9]+,[^0-9]*[0-9]+/' file
or
awk '/[0-9]+, =[0-9]+/' file
```